# How to support new wooden floor joists on stone and clay foundation walls

Tags: floor

I'd like to ask you for some best practice sharing, or advice .

**My situation:**
I'm about to make new wooden floor in old house with walls made of clay and huge rocks. The walls are therefore a bit crooked/sinuous. The base of the floor is about 1,5 feet below the actual top floor level - it is approx. 1/2 ft gravel laid on earth. The room is some 16x12 feet large. I want to keep the methods as much traditional as possible (no concrete, no plastic supports, ...)

**My plans:**
I'd like to attach steel L-profile (or wooden joist alternatively) along all walls (I want to mount it to the big rocks they should be ok to hold it) in the same level. Then I want to lay the floor joist on the L-profiles and support it in in some 3 points. On these joist I want to lay the wooden floor boards. For insulation I want to cover the gravel with foam glass up to the level of the joists.
See this image: http://lowcosttraveltips.com/floor-joist-wall.PNG

**My doubts:**

1. for sure it is the easiest way how to make it, but is it good
   idea to make it that way?
2. what can I use as support "pillars"? are eg. rocks or bricks ok (I have a lot of older bricks)? or would they suck humidity and then transfer it to wood and rotten in?
3. should I make any kind of hydro isolation between steel L-profiles and wooden joist and between bricks and joists?
4. how many supporting pillars
   do I need for the joist length of 16 feet?
5. should I mount the
   floor joist to the steel L-profiles (problems with dilatation)? or
   can I mount it at only one side and let other side to "move"?

   THank you for any help, advice and even possibly critique of my
   amateur ideas.

Mario

Comment: What does "traditional" mean? Concrete has been around for centuries. Steel and foam glass has not. This question leans more toward hobby construction than actual home improvement.

Comment: you are right, foam glass is modern material. Ok, maybe I should write something like natural way, in meaning, that I don't want to use plastics, oil-based glues, and other materials they are leaking chemicals (insecticides, ... ). it is personal preference. I believe it is home improvement, because I am really building new floor - just not using the most usual modern method ... anyway, if you feel like I'm in wrong forum I can look for some more adequate ...